# Vue.js v-validate get value from model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can one pass value from model to v-validate (VeeValidate) directive.

```
 v-validate="'required|unique-email:model.Email'"
```

Obviously, i would like to replace `model.Email` with variable from `data`.

Here's validate code

```
VeeValidate.Validator.extend('unique-email', {
    messages: {
        en: (field, args) => {
            return "Email Taken";
        }
    },
    validate: (value, args) => {
        return profileService.emailTaken(value).then((response) => {
            console.log(args); <-- i need email model in here,
            var emailTaken = response.data;
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve({
                    valid: !emailTaken
                    //data: value !== 'trigger' ? undefined : { message: 'Not this value' }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is

```
v-validate="'required|unique-email:' + model.Email"
```

That will add model.Email as the first element of the `args` array in

```
validate: (value, args)
```

Also, for what it's worth,

```
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve({
                valid: !emailTaken
                //data: value !== 'trigger' ? undefined : { message: 'Not this value' }
            });
        });
```

can be shortened to

```
return Promise.resolve({valid: !emailTaken});
```

Comment: wow thanks. i was so close in one of my tries. i missed `+` :) thanks.